# What ways to consider when sharing code between two constructors

Tags: constructor

assume we have :

```
class Dictionary {
    int n;
    int *ints;
    char **strs;
    inline void init(int n);
public:
    Dictionary(int n);
    Dictionary(const Dictionary& dic);
};
```

and :

```
Dictionary::Dictionary(int n) {
    init(n);
}

void Dictionary::init(int n) {
    this->n=n;
    ints=new int[n];
    strs=new char*[n];
}
Dictionary::Dictionary(const Dictionary& dic){
    init(n);
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        ints[i]=dic.ints[i];
        strs[i]=dic.strs[i];
    }
}
```

is there a more effcient way to share the code in init?

Comment: Efficient how? Inlining it to the class declaration would be a start. Make it private perhaps?

Comment: Efficiency of code elegance, performance memory-wise and runtime-wise and other program engineering considerations

Comment: I don't understand what further option you would expect. I'd want to do away with method bloat but you have declared 3 public methods in your class so I don't know how to help.

Comment: suggest your own approach, mine was just to make you undestand what im trying to acheive which is sharing code between diffrent constructors.

Comment: If that is all then `private`ise the shared code and put the function body inline with the declaration or at least in the same file. My mistake you have already privatised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In header:

```
class Dictionary {
    int n;
    int *ints;
    char **strs;
    inline void init(int n) {
        this->n=n;
        ints=new int[n];
        strs=new char*[n];
    }

public:
    Dictionary(int n);
    Dictionary(const Dictionary& dic);
};
```

and else where:

```
Dictionary::Dictionary(int n) {
    init(n);
}

Dictionary::Dictionary(const Dictionary& dic){
    init(n);
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        ints[i]=dic.ints[i];
        strs[i]=dic.strs[i];
    }
}
```

More likely to inline the shared code then, for efficiency.